# ui-select directive doesn't display

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

i am going to use ui-select directive, i have added `select.js` and `select.css` to the project and this is my code in view :

```
<ui-select ng-model="Client.selected" theme="bootstrap"     style="width:300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select an item ...>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in Client.rules | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Client.rules contain a list of items containing 'id' and 'name' which gets populated in the controller.

After running the page I have no errors on console but ui-select doesn't show.

Comment: Have you added the directive code ?

Comment: I solve it. i hadn't register the ui-select to module.